# Sqlite Fetching EXC_BAD_ERROR

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am fetching some details from database, while fetching i got an error like EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
This error doesn't occurs regularly, it occurs randomly. Due to this i am not able to solve the issue. Please see the attached image, whether this occurs due to empty database.[image]